# Unable to see list of tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer

I am using SQL Developer and now I can `SELECT` but viewing those tables in the list is not available. Is there some configuration I need to do in order to see the tables? User has select all tables privileges.

I am expanding the tree under my own user, not under the user who owns the tables.

Answer (score 6):

For where you are looking, you can only see the tables that exist in the schema that belongs to the user you supplied in your connection details.

If you want to see 'the tables' - you need to expand the 'Other Users' node, and explore the users there, and go to their respective tables list.

If you can query these objects in a worksheet w/o adding a SCHEMA. prefix to the FROM clause, it's because there is a SYNONYM that allows you to do so.

You can configure SQLDev to show these SYNONYMS as tables in your tree.

[image]

I talk about how to do this [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/).